# How do I count how often a method was called within 10 milliseconds?

Tags: c#

I have a sensorlistener which runs the method "onsensorchanged" every single time an event has occured. Now I want to know how often this method is executed within 10 millisecond.

I have a timespan (current Timestamp- previous Timestamp), which should execute "counter++" when my timespan(total millisec) is smaller then 10.
Unfortunately my counter is always 0 somehow.
I did the initializiation outside of the onSensorChanged method because it would always initialize each time the method would be running (to 0).

```
DateTime timestamp;
DateTime timestampAlt;
TimeSpan deltaT;
int counter = 0;

public void OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent e)
{
    timestamp = System.DateTime.Now;    //timestamp of now
    deltaT = timestamp - timestampAlt;  //delta of timestamp of event 1 and event 2

    //if delta between two events happened before 10 milli sec past, ignore
    if (deltaT.TotalMilliseconds <= 10 || deltaT.TotalMilliseconds <= -10) //deltaT.Seconds <= 0.01
    {
        counter++;
        return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(counter);

    //if 10 ms past, our previous timestamp become the old
    timestampAlt = timestamp;
}
```

Comment: A System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch() is the thing to use for millisecond timing, the update frequency of .Now is not guaranteed at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DateTime.Now` itself may take too much time being calculated, you'll be better off using a `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`.

Something like this:

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
int counter = 0;

public void OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent e)
{
    if (!stopwatch.IsRunning)
    {
        // start the stopwatch
        stopwatch.Start();
    }
    else
    {
        if (stopwatch.ElapsedMiliseconds <= 10)
        {
            counter++;
            return;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(counter);

    // 10ms passed, restart the stopwatch
    stopwatch.Restart();
}
```